# React - Component is not updated after re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux

After a re-render, one of my components doesn't get updated. I t only happens occasionally.

I checked if the component renders properly. On the code below, you'll see a `console.log` in the `render` function. I realized that the value changes correctly. But the component itself doesn't update visually. I don't think that I mutate any states/props. I use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for most state management. Do you know why that might happen? Thank you.

Child component looks like this:

```
export default ChildComponent extends React.Component {
   ...

   render() {
      ...
      const barWidth = this.getProgressWidth(boundingClientRect) // also uses this.props.editorTimestamp
      console.log(barWidth) // This value is updated like I expect

      return (
         <div>
            ...
            <div style={{...styles.barStyles, width: barWidth }}>
            ...
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Parent component looks like this:

```
export default ParentComponent extends React.Component {
   ...

   render() {
      ...
      const singleEditorTimestamp = this.getEditorTimestamp(id) // gets the timestamp from timestamps obj

      return (
         <div>
            ...
            <ChildComponent editorTimestamp={singleEditorTimestamp} />
            ...
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it would be wise to store `barWidth` in state, this way it updates with the state change that is triggering the re-render.

Comment: You are right. Prop changes trigger re-renders, as well. PureComponent can be re-rendered depending on whether prop changed by doing a shallow comparison (reference diff). Probably not a good answer so I removed it as it doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @silencedogood I could do that but it would add an additional ```setState``` to the lifecycle. And ```barWidth``` changes too much so I don't want to do that. Moreover, this happens very rarely.

Comment: are you sure about your dispatching a correct action and redux will work correctly in your case?
please update your post and add your reducer and the way your app connected to redux

Comment: @novonimo I added it

Answer (score -1):

The `state` or `props` changes can trigger the render. Also `this.forceUpdate();`

You can do like

```
 const barWidth = this.getProgressWidth(boundingClientRect)
 this.setState({barWidth: barWidth});
```

But changing state inside render is not good idea. Because it will trigger infinite rendering process. You should declare one `event` and change `state` in that event. :)

Comment: I don't use ```setState``` inside ```render``` function. Actually right now, I'm trying to avoid using it in ```componentDidUpdate```. Because, in my code block, ```this.props.editorTimestamp``` changes. The component gets rendered (I can see that from the console.log in the render function), however it doesn't gets updated visually. I didn't understand why that happens.

Comment: Oh I was understand wrong. Here is the what you are trying to do https://medium.com/@ItsMeDannyZ/how-to-build-a-progress-bar-with-react-8c5e79731d1f :D

Comment: Thank for the post but my progress bar is working. I'm just trying to understand why it doesn't respond to prop changes sometimes.